# Date Box show below the pop up screen in jquery mobile.?

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to show date box above the pop up screen .Actually I am try to implement date box but it is showing below the pop up screen .Here is fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/3yG9E/

```
 - <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title></title>

    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">

    <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
    <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <!--script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script-->
    <!--script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script-->
     <script src="lib/jquery.textselect.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.scrollTo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.search.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PopupScript.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CasePadDatabase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/websocket.js"></script>
    <script src="js/BackButtonImplentation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fontSizeFunctionality.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CreateFolder.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/WebSocketPlugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/highlight.js"></script>
    <script src="js/EmailComposer.js"></script>


    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" /-->
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />       
    <!--script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script-->        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script> 





</head>


<body>
    <!--**********************************Home page Star******************************-->
    <div data-role="page" id="Home" > 
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
            <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">My Cases</h1>
            <div class="ui-btn-right" id="headerButtons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#UserSettingScreen" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Setting</a>
                <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup" id="Add" data-position-to="window">Add</a>
                <a href="" data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup"id="Edit" data-position-to="window">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderData" >
            </ul>
            <!-- **************Case Information Pop up Start*******************-->
            <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none"  data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                    <h1>Case Information</h1>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" >
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>
                        <!--input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h"  -->
                        <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="text-12" class="caseTextArea_h"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Actually i have header having button .on click it show pop up screen on click date field it is showing below the pop up screen .How to show date box above the pop up screen may i change z index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick fix is to add `"zindex":1200` to your data-options object in your date-box input

Comment: can you please add in my fiddle?

Comment: sir i have one more question to search a text from page ?

Comment: error is display like this .There is no mode by that name loaded/mode not given

Comment: I tested the fiddle on iPad and it's kind of sluggish but it works. Make sure you have the data-options parameter the same as in the fiddle

Comment: can you please tell me the search text as i do lot of RND .And i have two fiddle please see below my comments

Comment: Here's what I could do with the search plugin, just make sure to include the necessary Javascript files and it seems it only works when the content is divided in different elements so it'll only searach once per element http://jsfiddle.net/SCfPQ/9/

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..It is not work on div because i have real time data which is i append on div .that why i am asking actually i append data in div which is coming on server,,

Comment: hello sir ..!! i integrate my date box in my code But it is working well.But there is an image which is display end of field(on click that image date box open ).it is not displaying ..here is my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip

Answer (score 0):

This is from [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/).

Note: Chaining of popups not allowed

The framework does not currently support chaining of popups so it's not possible to embed a link from one popup to another popup. All links with a data-rel="popup" inside a popup will not do anything at all.

This also means that custom select menus will not work inside popups, because they are themselves implemented using popups. If you place a select menu inside a popup, it will be rendered as a native select menu, even if you specify data-native-menu="false".

A workaround to get chained popups working is the use of a timeout for example in the popupafterclose event bound to the invoking popup. In the following example, when the first popup is closed, the second will be opened by a delayed call to the open method:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", function() {
    $( '.popupParent' ).on({
        popupafterclose: function() {
            setTimeout( function(){ $( '.popupChild' ).popup( 'open' ) }, 100 );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure that you want this.  The 'work around' will close the original pop-up.  I would think that you want that to stay open.

Comment: I'm not sure.  The date box is by nature a pop-up. Can you make the form not a pop-up?

Comment: yes i need to open first pop up screen the select date field.

Comment: after selecting date then user may close popup screen

Comment: So you need the form to be a pop-up?

Comment: This is hackish, but you could try setting the position of the date box further down.  That is just bad UI design but it would allow you to see it.

Comment: Then click (+) on header .It show pop up screen .Then there is filed case date here i need to show date box..

Comment: I did look at your fiddle.  I am just wondering if you can make your form a form instead of a pop-up.  Are you allowed?

Comment: Yeah, I saw it too and up voted it. Good luck with your app. :)

Comment: sir i have one more question to search a text from page ?

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do.  I used a jQuery Highlight plugin before that would highlight every occurrence of the text typed in the search box. It was called jquery.highlight-3.js

Comment: yes i search this i do't need like this .I need like a search button, next , previous button.functionality.like this https://github.com/nmartynenko/jquery-search-plugin

Comment: can you do some favour for me .actually from last two days i am looking f.or that but no success .Can you add this plugin on this.so that it will work..http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/SCfPQ/1/

Comment: here is my fiddle.of search i need to add that functionality on this fiddle

Comment: i also try this by it is work fine first time But second time it will not work..http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/wjLmx/2/